# How to watch content of http request sending from java application (by com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client)?

Tags: java, http, sniffing

I send http request.

I use `com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client`

I cannot find way how to show content of http request.

```
 public ClientResponse execute() throws RestException {
        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
        authenticateIfNeed(client);
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(getCommandUrl());
        if (Method.POST == getMethod()) {
            webResource = webResource.queryParams(parameters);
        } else {
            webResource = client.resource(getCommandUrl() + (!parameters.isEmpty() ? "?" + createParametersString() : ""));
        }
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug("request parameters  = " + parameters);
        }
        try{
            ClientResponse clientResponse = webResource.accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE).method(getMethod().name(), ClientResponse.class);
            if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("Response = " + clientResponse);
            }
            checkExpectedStatus(clientResponse.getClientResponseStatus());
            return clientResponse;
        }catch (UniformInterfaceException | ClientHandlerException e ){
            throw new RestException(e);
        }
```

I tryed to use eclipse tcp ip monitor but I have failure.

**UPDATE**

In debug I watch `webResource.getURI().getAuthority()`

I get string with format:

```
host:port
```

[image]

I write correspond `Host name` and `Port` there and this port to field `local monitoring port`

Could you help to solve problem?

Comment: Where do you need to show the content of the response of your HTTP request? Also, what problems (failures) you have when using Eclipse TCP?

Comment: I do not know to use it